# Using sprite images within li on hover

Tags: jquery, css, sprite

I have an image saved as a sprite (a star) originally for changing colour on hover status. I wanted to adapt its use to show X amount of stars depending on class name for example.

I understand changing the background position will change which image is shown on hover, as the images are sat vertically.

Example

```
.sprite {
 width:46px;
 height:44px;
 background:url(image.gif) 0px 0px;
}        

.sprite:hover{
  background: url(image.gif) 0px 44px;
}
```

I want to be able to repeat the image a certain length right to reveal  x amount of stars, 1, 2 , 3 or 4 on hover..the amount of stars shown will be pre defined, Is this possible?

At the moment the example i have made shows 4 stars as thats how many fit within the div, if my div was wider then more stars would be shown.

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/qvAPz/2/) with two examples, the first i have made with just normal divs to show what i am trying to achieve, the second is using an li element, its this one i am struggling with.

Comment: You can use good [CSS Star Rating Redux](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/01/css-star-rating-redux/) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're going for here, but here's a fiddle with a working example on the `<li>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/nsFRq/3/

Here is the code:

```
$('.rateable').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.text').stop().hide();
    $(this).find('.rate').stop().animate({
        left: 400,
        opacity: "show"
    }, 1500);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.rate').stop().hide();
    $(this).find('.text').stop().fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: thank you, ok so if i only wanted 3 stars to show on hover instead of the 4, how would i do that whilst keeping the width of the li at 81px?

Answer (score 1):

You may use class and multiple background:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvAPz/3/

```
.rate50 {
    background:
         url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/richlewisprofile/assets/images/rate.png') 40px -24px no-repeat,
         url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/richlewisprofile/assets/images/rate.png') 60px -24px no-repeat, 
         url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/richlewisprofile/assets/images/rate.png');
}
```

Comment: the height of your element cannot exceed the height of one star in your sprite, else you'll see both stars (goldish and grayish) .Because of your img, this height is around 20px . You can rearrange your sprite, giving more space in between sprites :)